# Sql query in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have this query written in Microsoft Access:

```
SELECT p.artnbr                            AS [Number], 
   p.name                              AS Name, 
   s.sizename                          AS Sizes, 
   s.sizeindex                         AS SizeIndex, 
   s.oid                               AS SizeId, 
   l.name                              AS LocationName, 
   (SELECT od.quantity 
    FROM   orderdetails od 
    WHERE  od.ORDER = (SELECT o.oid 
                       FROM   [order] o 
                       WHERE  o.active = -1 
                              AND o.location = l.oid) 
           AND od.productsize = s.oid) AS Quantity 
FROM   [size] AS s 
   INNER JOIN (product AS p 
               INNER JOIN (favorite AS f 
                           INNER JOIN location AS l 
                                   ON f.customer = l.customer) 
                       ON p.oid = f.product) 
           ON p.oid = s.product 
WHERE  f.customer = @customer
```

The link below shows tables i used and their relationships.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18377860/QueryTables.png

This query returns a correct result, but as u can see i am using a Sub query to get the quantity. I cant figure out how can i rewrite this query using join statements instead of that long sub-query. Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

EDIT: To make it more clear, my query needs to get all unique combinations of (product, size, location) whether they have an [Order] or not and display ordered quantity. If an order does not exist for a particular combination the quantity should be null.

EDIT2: 
I managed to build the query and it looks like this:

```
SELECT p.ArtNbr                    AS [Number], 
   p.Name                          AS Name, 
   s.SizeName                      AS Sizes, 
   s.SizeIndex                     AS SizeIndex, 
   s.Oid                           AS SizeId, 
   l.Name                          AS LocationName, 
   so.qty                          AS Quantity
FROM ([Size] AS s 
         INNER JOIN (Product AS p 
               INNER JOIN (Favorite AS f 
                           INNER JOIN Location AS l 
                                   ON f.Customer = l.Customer) ON p.OID = f.Product) 
                       ON p.OID = s.Product) 
      LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT od.ProductSize       AS PS, 
                  od.Quantity          AS qty, 
                  o.Location as Location 
           FROM OrderDetails AS od INNER JOIN [Order] AS o ON od.Order = o.OID 
           WHERE o.Active = -1)  AS so ON so.PS = s.OID
WHERE f.Customer = @customer AND (l.OID = so.Location OR so.Location is null)
```

I did like Matt said, i moved the sub-query into the FROM section, i included ProductSize and Location in the select query of the derived table, then linking the result with "Size" table and i finally added a condition to the where section to eliminate the repetition of the same record for each Location.

Comment: It looks to me like you should be using LEFT JOINs.

Comment: I tried using left joins but it didn't work for me, can you write it for me please. Thanks

Comment: @Elie I suggest moving your "sub-select" into the FROM section, and to include 'location' and 'productsize' as part of a 'derived table', you can then link this back in the same way and performance should be improved.

Comment: @Matt Thank you for your reply, can you give more details about your solution or a quick example

Comment: Elie, why not try some of the suggestions and post back your attempts? People like to see an effort, rather being asked "do it for me". BTW "did not work" is never enough information.

Comment: @Elie I agree with Remou, I know it's unfortunate but we're not here to simply write it for you. I would like to give an example but without the tables and their structures infront of me to play around with I'm struggling to pick apart this query. Basically you want to create a separate query for your sub-select which returns all the values, then link this back in with the rest of the query, the query designer should be able to handle this.

Comment: @Matt I shared a link showing a picture of the tables and structure, but don't worry anymore because after some readings i figured out what you mean and i managed to build the query. I will add the answer now and thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @Elie Glad you were able to produce the desired result, if possible could you post it as a separate answer rather than an addition to the question, it will then show as been answered when people are searching through the site and may benefit others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to build the query and it looks like this:

```
SELECT p.ArtNbr                    AS [Number], 
   p.Name                          AS Name, 
   s.SizeName                      AS Sizes, 
   s.SizeIndex                     AS SizeIndex, 
   s.Oid                           AS SizeId, 
   l.Name                          AS LocationName, 
   so.qty                          AS Quantity
FROM ([Size] AS s 
         INNER JOIN (Product AS p 
               INNER JOIN (Favorite AS f 
                           INNER JOIN Location AS l 
                                   ON f.Customer = l.Customer) ON p.OID = f.Product) 
                       ON p.OID = s.Product) 
      LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT od.ProductSize       AS PS, 
                  od.Quantity          AS qty, 
                  o.Location as Location 
           FROM OrderDetails AS od INNER JOIN [Order] AS o ON od.Order = o.OID 
           WHERE o.Active = -1)  AS so ON so.PS = s.OID
WHERE f.Customer = @customer AND (l.OID = so.Location OR so.Location is null)
```

I did like Matt said, i moved the sub-query into the FROM section, i included ProductSize and Location in the select query of the derived table, then linking the result with "Size" table and i finally added a condition to the where section to eliminate the repetition of the same record for each Location.